# Bulk Image Resizing with PHP and ImageMagick

Tags: php, batch-file, imagemagick

In the early days of my site, I allowed people to upload any size image they wanted.  I now have client and server side config to limit new images to 2000px max, while maintaiing the origional ratio.

So from the old config I have a heap of directories with large images that I need to scale down, I would like to do this on the server side in batch (due to client side bandwidth limitations), and for the life of me I cant work it out.  I realise it will cause server side high CPU, so I will do it in groups spread over a few days.

Due to Host RAM limitations I cant use GD for scaling, so I have ImageMagick avail to me.

An example of a group I would do in 1 batch looks like this:
/ Images / 01 / 101 / abc.jpg
/ Images / 01 / 101  / random.jpg
/ Images / 01 / 101  / randomfile.jpg
/ Images / 01 / 184 / random.jpg
/ Images / 01 / 184 / photo.jpg
/ Images / 03 / 372 / randomnumber.jpg
/ Images / 03 / 372 / randomanything.jpg

So I am after something that can:

- Recursivly go through all directories and sub-directories looking for JPGs, when it finds one -

  - Work out the current ratio
  - Rename the origional file to origional.jpg.old
  - resize the file to a max of 2000px in height/width, while mainting aspect ratio
  - write file to disk using the origional.jpg file name
  - check that the new origional.jpg is a valid happy file

    - And if its a happy file delete origional.jpg.old
- Then process the next file/folder.

I am stuck, and would love any help please.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: By the way, I can also use cpanel Image Scaler, if anyone knows how to use that in Batch?

Comment: I'm still new around here so forgive me if this comment is unwarranted, but this looks an awful lot like asking people to do your work for you.  What exactly are you stuck on?  You've given us enough specs to write the program but no idea of what you've actually done or are having problems achieving.

Answer (score 3):

> Recursively go through all directories and sub-directories looking for JPGs, when it finds one

Use a combination of `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, possibly together with `RegexIterator`. There are a few examples in this site.

> Work out the current ratio

Unnecessary.

> Rename the origional file to origional.jpg.old

See [`rename`](http://pt2.php.net/rename).

> resize the file to a max of 2000px in height/width, while mainting aspect ratio

See `Imagick::resizeImage` or `Imagick::scaleImage`.

> write file to disk using the origional.jpg file name

`Imagick::writeImage`

> check that the new origional.jpg is a valid happy file

Unnecessary.

> And if its a happy file delete origional.jpg.old

See [unlink](http://pt2.php.net/unlink).

Comment: thanks for that, should give me what I need, thanks for your help.